# How to set page content to center of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I need is to show the content of a web page in the center of the browser, no matter what screen size it is, big or small, resolution high or low, it always gets automatically adjusted to the center of the browser.
Thanks in advance

My Html and css code is below

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="basic1.css"/>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="menu">
        <a href = "#"><img class="imgc" src="img.png" alt="icon"/></a>
        <a href = "#"><img class="imgd" src="do.png" alt="do"/></a>
    </div>
        <div id="smenu"></div>
    <div id="mainbox">
        <div class="ibox"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menutext">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><b>???????</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>?????</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>?????</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="py">
        <pre class="p">??<span style="color:black;font-size:25px">??????</span></pre>
        <pre class="s">?? ???? ??? ??? <span style="color:#980000;
        letter-spacing :+1mm"><b>:3</b></span></pre>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
#menu img.imgc {
position:absolute;
right:77%;
top:10px;
margin:0px auto;
}
#menu img.imgd {
position:absolute;
left:75%;
top:10px;
margin:0px auto;
}
#menu {
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:0%;
right:0%;
right:0%;
width:100%;
height:125px;
border-bottom:1px solid #C8C8C8;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:#E8E8E8; 
}
#mainbox div.ibox{
position:absolute;
left:31%;
top:20px;
border-left:3px solid gray;
height:105px; 
margin:0px auto;
}
#menutext ul{
position:absolute;
right:72%;
top:15px;
list-style: none;
line-height:30px;
margin:0px auto;
}
#menutext a{
font-size:12px;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-family:Lucida,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-weight:500; 
color:black;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
}
#py pre.p{
position:absolute;
top:15px;
left:33%;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
letter-spacing : +2mm;
font-size:50px;  
color:#009933;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
margin:0px auto;
}
#py pre.s{
position:absolute;
top:67px;
left:33%;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
letter-spacing : +3mm;
font-size:12px;  
color:gray;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put all the content inside a div, set its class to `container`:

```
<div class="container">
   ...
</div>
```

Then using css set its margins to auto:

```
.container{
    margin:0px auto;
    width: 600px; 
}
```

have a look [at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm9sx/2/)

**EDIT**

check [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm9sx/7/) , the `menu` css doesn't neet all of what you wrote, should be something like:

```
#menu {
height:125px;
border-bottom:1px solid #C8C8C8;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:#E8E8E8; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all your page content inside a wrapper div, then give it some relative width (e.g. 50%) and auto horizontal margins.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</div>
```

CSS (50% page width, zero top/bottom margin):

```
#wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put another div around all of your content (so from right after your body start tag and just before body end tag). Call it `<div class="container">`

Set the following style to that div:

```
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
```

This should center your content.

You can change the width as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fundation3's grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution.**

```
<html>
          <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                html
                {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                body
                {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            This is text!
        </body>
</html>
```